# POST http://localhost:8080/projects1 400 (Bad Request) in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

### index.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="project_name"/>
<button ng-click="add_project()">Add Project</button>
```

### controller.js

```
$scope.add_project = function add_project(){
  console.log($scope.project_name);
  $http.post('/projects', $scope.project_name).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    refresh();
  });
};
```

### server.js

```
app.post('/projects',function (req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  db.projects.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});
```

When I click the button I am getting the error:

> angular.js:11821 PUT http://localhost:8080/projects1 400 (Bad Request)

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You have `http://localhost:8080/projects`` but your route is just for `/projects` is that a typo? Also are you using `body-parser` in your `server.js`? `$http.post` automatically sends all requests with a `Content-Type=application/json` header.

Comment: yes i am using body-parser, and it doesnt work even if i use http://localhost:8080/projects' in the route

Comment: Please show ur code of node.js server configuration

Comment: you can check the full code here https://github.com/utkarsh17ife/project_tracker

Comment: this is the full error? check on the console log section